# while loop using google charts

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So im having this issue, im pulling numbers from a database, for hits on a page. The pie chart worked fine when there was only one country in the database, now theres a few, but it grabs from the top 5. It worked fine but i think my while loop is screwed up, how would i reformat it so it works?`

Database query:

```
$csel = $odb->query("SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM bots GROUP BY country ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 5");
```

display:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Total Bots'],
          <?php
  while ($c = $csel->fetch())
                                    {
                    $top2 = geoip_country_name_by_id($gi, $c[0]);
                    $top = number_format($c[1]);
                                        echo ("['$top2', '$top']");

  }
```

I figured it was because i didnt have a comma at the end of the echo, so i tried that and the pie chart was grey and said "other"

I think i need to somehow make a string that does what the echo says, and adds a comma until the last piece of data.

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Create the complete dataset in PHP as an array and use `json_encode()` to convert it to json. That's way easier and safer than manually building the json-data.

Comment: You need a comma after each JS array I think. ^ is probably a better suggestion though.

Comment: yeah but how would i go about doing that

Comment: Just create an array and then append the data for each row in the while loop. Give it a shot.

Comment: yeah i cant seem to figure this out, is there an example code that could aid me?

Comment: okay ive converted it to json, now how do i put it into the chart?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['time', 'Price'],
          <?php  while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
                echo "[' ".$r["timestamp"]." ', ".$r["totalprice"]." ],";
          } ?>  
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```